# Using Express Mergeparams with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express

I'm using Typescript for my small project and I'm encountering a problem. I'm nesting my router but Typescript doesn't seem to recognize the parent's parameter.

On the "child" file I have

```
const childRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

childRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const userName = req.params.username; 
    // This causes the error, Property 'username' does not exist on type '{}'
});
```

and then on the "parent" file the code is

```
import childRouter from './child';

const parentRouter = express.Router();

parentRouter.use('/:username', childRouter);
```

I have no idea how to fix this, it seems like typescript doesn't recognize that I'm using the parent's parameter. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy fix, but you could always change the router and parent paths, or ditch the router entirely.

Comment: Trackback to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/64437 where I'm reporting this as a bug with Express types

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't infer it from the actual parent route.

The cleanest way to do it, is to use generics:

```
import { RouteParameters } from 'express-serve-static-core';

type WithParentParams<T extends string> = RouteParameters<':userName'> & RouteParameters<T>
//                       Add any other parent params here -^^^^^^^^^

const route = '/' as const;

childRouter.get<typeof route, WithParentParams<typeof route>>(route, async (req, res) => {
  const { userName } = req.params;
```

It's a little convoluted, because you have to set up the `WithParentParams` and repeat the route as the first param in `childRouter.get<routeType, paramsType>`.

Still, it's better to be explicit than type casting.

Comment: I had to install `@types/express-serve-static-core` ONLY and not `express-serve-static-core`. Having both prioritizes the latter. In my setup at least. I found this post after trying to import `RouteParameters`, and your answer was a great hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the post the first time.

The `request.params` should be of following type if you installed the types properly for Express.

```
interface ParamsDictionary {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

If you need to force type, you can also do following:

```
const username = req.params.username as string
```

Comment: _"I don't know if Router.use() supports params"_. It does, and OP's use case is perfectly valid.

Comment: Oh right, I misread the post now, that I'm reading it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a not ideal but not bad, versatile solution to this problem, considering that there's no way to be aware of parent's parameters.

```
type parentParam = { username: string };

childRouter.get('/:childId', (req, res) => {
    const { userName, childId } = req.params as typeof req.params & parentParam;
    ...
```

You can declare parent's parameters that the child is not aware of, and add other child parameters in the route if any.
This will keep native's Express TS type checking for existing parameters on the child, and also of course for the parent's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any 'good' solution so far
But I did this, which works pretty nice:

(all for the sake of type support...)

`userid.ts`

```
const userIdRouterConstuctor = (userid: string) => {

  router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`User id is now: ${userid}`);
  });

  return router;
};

export default userIdRouterConstuctor;
```

and now you can create a new router in `users` that has the userid available to it...

`users.ts`

```
router.use("/:userid", (req, res, next) => {
  const { userid } = req.params;
  userIdRouterConstuctor(userid)(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a dirty solution:

```
childRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.params as any;
  …
});
```